# How to apply different hover color effect to different li using css

Tags: html, css

I have created ul inside nav tag so I want to apply different background-color hover effect to different li but hover effect is applied to only anchor tag not complete li.

CSS property I have mentioned like this

```css
.main-menu .acc .fa-home,
.main-menu .acc>a:hover {
  background-color: #689f38;
}

.main-menu .fa-laptop,
.main-menu li>a:hover {
  background-color: #ed3b3b;
}

.main-menu .fa-list,
.main-menu .has-list>a:hover {
  background-color: #ef6c00;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="acc">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
           List One
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-subnav">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
            List Two
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-list">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="nav-text">
           List Three
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: why not `li:hover` ?

Comment: @ashishsingh then same color effect will apply to all li but i want every li hover background-color should different

Comment: your `li` tags have different class you can use them to assign different color

Answer (score 1):

Just define `:hover` to the `li` element `li:hover` not `li>a:hover`

```css
.main-menu .acc .fa-home,
.main-menu .acc:hover{
    background-color:#689f38;
}

.main-menu .fa-laptop,
.main-menu li:hover{
    background-color:#ed3b3b;
}

.main-menu .fa-list,
.main-menu .has-list:hover{
    background-color:#ef6c00;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>

                <li class="acc">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                           List One
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            List Two
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li class="has-list">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                           List Three
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
```